# Float as key in map

Tags: java

Given a collection of `{Price, Quantity}` pair, I need to aggregate all quantities at same price point. What is the easiest way to achieve it?

A dirty-cut, would be to implement solution using `Hashmap` with keys being price and value being aggregated quantity. But, in my knowledge, `Float` isn't a safe key for `Hashmap`. So this solution is error-prone.

What is recommended alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: So use String as a key. What is the problem?

Comment: Define "price point?" Is it price within a certain range? You may wish to create a new class, one that holds a price value (myself, I'd use a BigDecimal for this), and that translates the price into a range, the range being used to determine a hashCode.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!! I was too caught up in problem to think of this simple solution. Thanks @AleksandrM

Comment: Make a `PricePoint` class, feed it the target`float` in the constructor, and use it as anchors for your price buckets.

Comment: IMO, you should never use `float` (or `Float`) for *anything*.  If you think you need `float`, then you need `double`.  But if you're working with money, and you think you need `double`, then you probably need an integer data type instead.

Comment: @jameslarge Your blanket statement is totally misleading, float is *the* type to use for storing large amounts of data (e.g. vertices, audio samples etc.) where the accuracy suffices - take a tour through openGL and you will find *lots* of float usage. Just because its not applicable in some domains (e.g. working with money amounts) doesn't mean there are no cases where you ever want to use it.

Comment: @Durandal, not _totally_ misleading.  I didn't mislead _you_.  Yeah, you're right.  I was too lazy to mention the storage use-case, but even that leads to a non-trivial discussion about floating point precision, and what it means, and how much you need, and when.  Considering that going from double to float only cuts the storage requirement by a mere 1/2, I will continue to advise noobs to stay away from `float`, but maybe I'll remember to tack on, "unless you _really_ know what you are doing" to the end of my rant.

Answer (score 9):

You could use BigDecimal as a key. It would be hashcode safe.

You'd have to initialize the values so they have the same scale, for instance:

```
BigDecimal key = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(price)).setScale(2);
```

Comment: BigDecimal has a precision too, and should definitely be used for financial fixed point values. Despite being verbose, and needing care.

Answer (score 2):

If all prices have fixed decimal size (2 digits for example), you can simply use `Long`, presenting price in cents, as a Map key.

Using `BigDecimal` is a bad option because it can lead to rare and hard-to-discover errors--two `BigDecimal`s are equal only if they have the same value and **the same precision** (thus `2.0` is not equal to `2.00` nor `2`--all three will become different keys in a map).